# Remove that extra line (called a newline) when printing in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new bee in python 3 and stuck here to remove \n while compiling code as given below, want to return two random lines with out printing \n and w/o square bracket [ ], what should i do?

code is

```py
import random 

def head(): 
    f = open("quotes.txt") 
    quotes = f.readlines() 
    f.close() 
    last=18 
    print(random.sample(quotes,2)) 

if __name__== "__main__": 
    head()
```

And executed this file the result returned as selected two random lines it is fine for me, but in the format like this included \n 
['IMPOSSIBLE says itself I M POSSIBLE\n', 'Never stops to Learning till dead end\n']

Comment: Please `format your code`

Comment: Hi @ForceBru, As i'm non-experienced programmer, i don't know how to format the code. can u please describe more in words?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting results like `['IMPOSSIBLE says itself I M POSSIBLE\n', 'Never stops to Learning till dead end\n']` is because it is `list` and you directly printing list as it is.

### Solution

Remove `print(random.sample(quotes,2))` and add following code

```py
tmp = random.sample(quotes,2)
for i in tmp:
    print(i,end="")
```

This will solve your problem and `end` in `print` is because your `quotes` already has newline so we are preventing `print` from inserting extra `\n`.

Comment: No, it's not defined as list, it is created in separate text file as name has given quote.txt file which placed at same path where i created this .py file and as run .py  and by which result is returned as selecting any random two quotes every times. and it is fine for me now i just want to remove \n and i did as you mentioned in thread but it gives me syntax error.

Comment: Yes You are reading from file but `f.readlines() ` return all lines in your text file as a list. Try it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved!!! 
I ran the code by typing command python which it was taken as python 2.7 and returned as this type of junk result, but it works fine as executed with python3 command.

Comment: I don't think so. Because I executed your code in question with python 3. I showed output like in your question. Did you changed your code?